# How do I copy music from iTunes to my iPad?

Tags: ipad, itunes

I seem to remember that dragging and dropping a file *used* to work the same as it did with my iPod.

Answer (score 6):

Click on the device, and on the main screen you need to set it to "manually manage music and videos." The reason it may still work on your iPod is that the setting is device specific.